# css keyframes animation on modal when closing

Tags: css, css-animations

This the css for my modal overlay and the container

```
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(20, 20, 21, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 350ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  }

  .container {
    background: var(--color-white);
    max-height: 94vh;
    max-width: 62.5rem;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation-name: slideUp;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 350ms;
    animation-timing-function: var(--animation-sharp);
  }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Basically, the overlay will fade in and at the same time the container will slide up. At moment, when the modal is being opened, animation is working as expect but there's no animation at all when it's being closed. How can I make sure that there will be reverse animation when closing? So when closing, the container will slide down and overlay will fade out.

Comment: Can u please share a snippet

Comment: Do I correctly assume, that when you are closing modal you set its `display` to `none`? If so - animation can't be visible for not displayed element.

Comment: @DawidRusnak yes the modal will be removed from the dom

Comment: Also add up your CSS.

Comment: When a modal is removed from DOM, you can't put any animation to it, as it doesn't exists anymore. Instead, on close, you should add a class (i.e. `modal--closed`) to it, and you can listen i.e. for `animationend` event (then you can remove this element from DOM). You may also look at this modal tutorial to see how it works: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/